# Matching two or patterns and swapping texts on all of them

Tags: linux, sed

I have a problem, where I need to change markup of one site to another. 
In first, I have it in this type: 
`[[https://stackoverflow.com/][StackOverflow]]`, where I need to change it to `[StackOverflow|https://stackoverflow.com/]` .

My sed command for this would be

```
sed -i 's/\[\[\(.*\)\]\[\(.*\)\]\]/\[\2|\1\]/g'
```

This works only if I have one matching pattern in line, for more it crashes. What I should change?

Comment: You may need to check [someone-answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  and  [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: You might ask me for  Python code. Why post a separate question?

Comment: Oh, haven't thought of you knowing python. Could you help me?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/FELrgU. And [I know Python](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/51/python?userid=3832970). :)

Comment: The idea is to do it in all .txt files in folder:
`import re

import glob, os
os.chdir("./dir")
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(file, 'r+') as f:
     for line in file:`
simple re.sub done on line with this code is going to work?

Comment: When you address someone, please add `@` before the username, I did not see the comment. Open the files for reading, create a file for writing and write updated lines to that new file.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but I want to change them in a original file, not write them to another file.

Comment: @Mark The thing is that you can't write to the same file. You will have to rename the temp file after the new file is created to replace the original one.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew started working for me, but it's adding weird spaces between lines and messes coding (in files where it's working it's ISO-8859-1), can help figure it out? https://pastebin.com/t9uR0zkc

Comment: Try something like https://pastebin.com/nzP3yMYK, note that you need to re-write the file after its handle is closed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew spaces now are OK, but still problem with letter like german umlauts etc. You have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: No idea what the problem is. Are you sure your file encoding is `encoding="latin1"`? Try `encoding="utf-8"`. `temp = open("temp.txt","w", encoding="utf-8")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match any 0 or more chars using `[^][]` negated bracket expression:

```
sed -i 's/\[\[\([^][]*\)\]\[\([^][]*\)]]/[\2|\1]/g' file
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/mfAzPV):

```
s="Text [[https://stackoverflow.com/][StackOverflow]] More text [[https://stackoverflow2.com/][StackOverflow2]]"
sed 's/\[\[\([^][]*\)\]\[\([^][]*\)]]/[\2|\1]/g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
Text [StackOverflow|https://stackoverflow.com/] More text [StackOverflow2|https://stackoverflow2.com/]
```